# borderRadius is the opposite of react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have a problem how can I use react native styles as shown below?

Image 1:I have a solution that is separating 2 rectangles and its borderRadius but how do borderRadius compare to its default?

[image]

[image]

Image2: ....

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you share some code on how you are trying to implement this? I think it will be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know ReactNative does not support this "inverted" border radius.
Some people achieve something similar to this using other Views as "Masks", there's a quite similar usecase as yours in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59082965/2719629

They got quite the expected result, but without the shadow.

One other option I would suggest is to use a svg between the two rectangles but that may be quite trick to implement, and svg's shadows don't work well with android as well.